# Change Express static path dynamically

Tags: express, loopbackjs

In Express you setup a static folder to serve your files through a middleware. From what I have understood this is then set throughout the applications lifecycle.

Is this possible to set somewhere in server.js for each request instead? For instance some requests uses "clientNew" folder while other requests uses "client". I want to be able to see the difference through a session-id, not through the URL.

Comment: Why don't you use CDN instead of express static? In case of CDN you can easily change the folder name at each request level

Comment: CDN is not an option here, we are working with multiple client folders and they will change/increase alot for a very low amount of users. What we need is an automatic solution were the static folder is changed depending on the version number in a request (currently stored in cookies). If not existing we just serve with default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while this is not a recommended approach for a an "open" application with lots of users due to optimization with caching and response time I solved it by doing a pointer to the static handler.

```
exports.createDynamicPath = function(app, path) {
  var static = app.loopback.static(path, { etag: false});
  var dynamicPath = function (req, res, next) {
    return static(req, res, next);
  }
  dynamicPath.setPath = function (newPath) {
    static = app.loopback.static(newPath, { etag: false})
  }
  return dynamicPath;
}

exports.determineClient = function(app, dynamicPath){
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.cookies && req.cookies.version != "client2"){
      dynamicPath.setPath("client");
    }else{
      dynamicPath.setPath("client2");
    }
    next();
  }
}
```

Based upon the variable in cookies it then switches path. Something worth noting is the disabling of etag, this is critical due to browsers storing previous client and determining if their file is still viable to keep.

This code is used early by the app, in this case Loopback (which by core uses Express).